# ConditionVariable not working in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, condition-variable

I need to wait for listener to check if image was sent correctly and then finish `AsyncTask`. But last log in `logcat` is "blocking...", so onComplete never triggers.

When I set initialization of condition varible to true, it's working but it doesn't wait on block(). I've seen many examples on `ConditionVariable` and I can't figure it out where my mistake is, it should be working.

```
private static class SendImageTask extends AsyncTask<SendImagePojo, Void, String> {
    private String KOFAX_TAG = "kofax";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(SendImagePojo... params) {
        Log.d(KOFAX_TAG, "doInBackground");

        final ConditionVariable condition = new ConditionVariable(false);

        params[0].kfx.sendImageService(params[0].doc, params[0].s, params[0].img, params[0].imageIndex, true, new ICompletionListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Void aVoid, Exception e) {
                Log.d(KOFAX_TAG, "onComplete");
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.e(KOFAX_TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());

                } else {
                    Log.d(KOFAX_TAG, "Image sent...");

                }

                condition.open();
            }
        });

        Log.d(KOFAX_TAG, "blocking...");

        condition.block();

        Log.d(KOFAX_TAG, "continuing...");

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know that condition.open() is getting called before condition.block? Do you see your log messages being printed before the "blocking" log?

Comment: onComplete never triggers before block().
Logcat:
doInBackground
blocking...

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to create synchronous request for sending image to API than creating asynchronous request with listener in task that already is working in background?

Comment: It would, but I'm using external library and it is not possible.

Comment: So instead of using AsyncTask you should probably use Service for that. Additionally AsyncTask is created for quick background jobs, I would not recognize sending picture to server for a quick job.

Comment: Is it throwing any execeptions?

Comment: In your comment you mean that you set the condition variable to true and it works but it doesn't block but in your code it shows the conditional variable is set to false. Which is it? if the conditional variable is set to true then the blocking call will do nothing because it's blocking() will only work when the conditional is false. When you set it to true, the conditional variable shouldn't block until so action happens and explicitly calls close() at which point block() will work as expected.